# A concurrency of Euler lines

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

[image: ConcurrentEulerLines]

I have obtained the concurrency of Euler lines in Poincare disk with Geogebra.
I want to know its synthetic proof.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: There are many concurrencies of Euler lines in Euclidean geometry. I am trying to find the concurrencies of Euler lines in hyperbolic geometry. In my example, the centroid is not similar to that of Euclidean geometry. I have used the centroid in the sense of V. Akopyan.